# Need regex or piece of data for slicing the code and handling quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Need help with writing a regex in python or need to slice this piece of data and then taking the double quotes separately

Tried the following piece of code for the input file but the initial lines contain the output as mentioned in the Actual Output, please help in rectifying the situation.

```
reader = csv.reader(file_sample, delimiter=delimiter, quotechar=quotechar, quoting= csv.QUOTE_ALL)
reader = csv.reader(x.replace('\0', '') for x in file_sample)
```

Actual Output:

```
CALLIN.csv0000700520310804322000005053126276127200687052113 0ustar  vzbaga2vmsuser"HEADER_ID","CAPITAL_ID","DIST_ID",
```

Expected Output:

```
HEADER_ID CAPITAL_ID DIST_ID
```

Comment: Maybe with `re`: `re.findall('"([A-Z_]+)"',your_string)`

Comment: But this is for processing of files and there is no input pattern, thing is the Actual Output is coming in the file first line, please let me know how the fields can be extracted without double quotes and this part of the output file:
CALLIN.csv0000700520310804322000005053126276127200687052113 0ustar  vzbaga2vmsuser

present in the file also gets removed.

Comment: The header is getting combined with detail record in the file, so, how it can be separated out using python?

Comment: Can you show what the beginning of your file looks like? I'm not sure I completely understand what you mean.

Comment: I think problem lies in line `x.replace('\0', '') for x in file_sample`. This will merge columns that are separated by `\0`. But without more info it's hard to tell.